# php single file cron job

Tags: php, batch-file, cron

how can I create a single PHP file that calls all files within the same folder sequentially. 
Im trying to create a simpler way to run all my php files ( Cron Jobs). 
 The way I am doing now is as follow :

**Batch file**

```
start /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\99003.php
start /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\78367.php
start /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\40937.php
//ect... I have more than 200 files I want to run one after another...
```

All files name are 5 digits number. I just get lost sometimes when adding or removing files.. 
Thanks

Comment: what have you already tried? and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have a batch file as stated above. I am not stuck, it works great but Im just trying to find out if I can create a cron job from a single file without having to write in the batch file all the file names.. because sometimes when I add or remove a file I have to go back and edit the batch file.. Im looking for a 'loop'?

Comment: The fact that you are trying to run more than 200 scripts once in an interval, on a windows box, using xampp, should tell you that in the whole construct, a design change might be considered usefull.

Comment: any advise is appreciated

Comment: @user3003977 : i understand you are looking for a 'loop'. But what have you already tried? And are you sure you want to loop in a PHP File? Why not write a .bat for it, that loops through all your PHP files?

Comment: It'd help to know / figure out why you need to run 200 individual scripts on a schedule like that.  You're almost certainly doing something that could be streamlined.

Comment: @nl-x the OP provided a bat file

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes, ... but in the OP he requests a PHP alternative. My suggestion is that he stays in the bat file construction.

Comment: I'll stick to the bat file as recommended. Thanks, Will go through the documentations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loop:

```
for /d %i in ("C:\xampp\*.php") do start /wait C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f %~fi
```

Sorry I lack information about all this atm.
$~fi is the fully qualified path name.

Hit this google link: https://www.google.de/search?q=windows+for+command+line+stackoverflow

You could also write a PHP script which calls all other PHP files, but PHP is different from command line (bat) in the way memory is used, scripts might block which you have to circumvent (using `proc_open()`), you would encounter timeouts.. `set_time_limit(0);`.

Using a batch file for your purpose seems a good approach, figure the parameters of the command line for the `for` command and you can do this in 1-3 lines of code.